# calling parent component function from child of siblings component in angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 component(comp1 and comp2) in main component that component2 has child component, I have tried to call a function in a component1 from child component of component2.

Comment: You need to reformulate your question. Show us the code you have written, so maybe we can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) usefull article about sharing data between Angular Components.

You can share Data via ViewChild or Output() and EventEmitter from child to parent(comp2 child to comp2) and then share these data to the sibling comp 1.
But i think the best way is to use a service where you can share data on unrelated Components

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to call a function between siblings component not sharing data between them.

Comment: @MinaFardin like sharing data you can use eventEmitter to call function from sibling component

Comment: I could not call directly function between child component  and sibling component. and because of that first of all I have tried to call parent function of child component then have called function of main component and finally I could access to child function of main component.
This will be clearer by drawing the shape but I could not share it.